# Nom d'une figure de style

Tags: figure-de-style

Si je dis :

> mon chien n'a pas inventé le fil à couper les croquettes.

est ce que cette blague peut être considérée comme une figure de style, et si oui, laquelle ?

Comment: On peut parler de  *personnification* , puisqu'on attribue des caractéristiques humaines à un animal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je dirais une cacologie :

[TLFi](https://www.le-tresor-de-la-langue.fr/definition/cacologie):

> CACOLOGIE,  *substantif féminin*
>   *Linguistique* «Terme employé parfois pour désigner une expression (...) défectueuse (...), qui, sans constituer une incorrection grammaticale, fait violence à l'usage, à la logique, etc.» (Mar. *L'exemple* 1933, page 42).
>   − *Par extension* Locution jugée vicieuse parce que contraire au bon usage de la langue commune.